# How do I run a .lua file?

Tags: file, lua

I need to run a .lua file with another .lua file.
Here is my code:

```
Program = io.read()
dofile(program)
```

I type the name of the file that I want to run correctly, but for some reason my compiler says that the file I typed does not exist. (Which it does)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lua is case sensitive; `Program` is not `program`
Otherwise the code should work.

Comment: You should "accept" this answer then (click the tick on the left)

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the full path instead of the relative path. i.e. `/home/nick/script.lua`