# Is there a function that executes a script?

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I'm trying to make a user interface with the clickdetector but I need to run/call another script to continue. Is there a function that does this?

```
local clickdetector = game.Workspace.CPU.Part.ClickDetector
clickdetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()

 -- What goes here? 

end)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a .lua file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585272/how-do-i-run-a-lua-file)

Comment: You might also want to consider 1) structuring your other file as a module and 2) executing the other file in a "sandbox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roblox has 3 notions of scripts. [Scripts](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/Script), [LocalScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/LocalScript), and [ModuleScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/ModuleScript). A ModuleScript is compiled once and the result is returned to any script that calls `require()` on it.

For example, you might have a module script that does some simple math for you. Let's call this script MathUtils

```
local MathUtils = {}
function MathUtils.add(a, b)
    return a + b
end

-- a module script must always return a value
return MathUtils
```

If you had another script next to MathUtils, you could include it like this :

```
local MathUtils = require(script.Parent.MathUtils)
print(MathUtils.add(1, 2))
```